# SQL Server query issue - ambiguous column

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have four tables :

1. `Applicant` (aid, aname)
2. `entrance_test` (Etid, etname)
3. `etest_centre` (etcid, location)
4. `etest_details` (aid, etid, etcid, etest_dt)

I want to select the number of applicants who have appeared for each test, test center wise.

This is my current query:

```
select 
    location, etname, count(Aid) as number of applicants
from 
    applicant as a 
inner join 
    etest_details as d on a.aid = d.aid 
inner join 
    Entrance_Test as t on t.Etid = d.Etid
inner join 
    Etest_Centre as c on c.Etcid = d.Etcid
group by 
    Location, Etname
```

This is the error I am getting :

> Ambiguous column name 'Aid'

Comment: The column name `aid` is in two tables that are being joined so its not clear which table you want the query to select the data from.. Use the table alas: `select count(a.aid)` or `count(d.aid)` depending on the table you want select the `aid` value.

Answer (score 1):

You have the column `aid` in multiple tables, and it doesn't know which to pick from.  You should specify which table it is from using the aliases you defined.

In this case, since a.Aid is the same as d.Aid (due to the `JOIN`), I'm using the `a` alias, but do keep in mind if `location` and `etname` also appear in multiple tables, you need to specify *which* table it should pick from.

```
Select      c.location, t.etname, Count(a.Aid) 
From        Applicant       As  a 
Inner Join  etest_details   As  d   On  a.aid = d.aid 
Inner Join  Entrance_Test   As  t   On  t.Etid = d.Etid
Inner Join  Etest_Centre    As  c   On  c.Etcid = d.Etcid
Group By    c.Location, t.Etname
```

As a rule of thumb, when you have multiple sources in one query, you should *always* be explicit about which table it should come from.  Even if you're sure it only exists in one of them, it's a good habit to get into to avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: I am going to go farther and say you should  be explicit about which table the field came from 100% of the time. It is just better for maintainability. I fail any code in code review  that doesn't do this because I have had to track down where a field came from in 20+ joins  in a complex reporting query and a not so obvious name to figure out the cause of a problem. It takes literally seconds to do this, there is no excuse for not doing it,

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the alias in the `COUNT` clause. Since you are using aliases, it would be better if you use them in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` sections as well. In this case, it should be :

```
SELECT          a.location,
                a.etname,
                COUNT(d.Aid) 

FROM            applicant AS a
INNER JOIN      etest_details AS d ON a.aid = d.aid 
INNER JOIN      Entrance_Test AS t ON t.Etid = d.Etid
INNER JOIN      Etest_Centre AS c ON c.Etcid = d.Etcid
GROUP BY        a.Location,
                a.Etname
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, i used the table name ' applicant.aid' but it did not work. I should have used aliases instead of the table name like 'a.Aid' or 'd.Aid'